# Prepros v.7.3.48 — как свернуть в трей?

Tags: windows, windows-10, компилятор

Вопрос, как свернуть этот компилятор в трей в windows 10? Чет все перелазил и не могу найти. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам просто надо запустить утилиту, она не покажет никакого окна, но будет работать в фоновом режиме. Сразу после этого почти любую программу можно свернуть в область уведомлений нажатием правой кнопки мыши по кнопке *«Свернуть»* в строке заголовка. Сворачиваются даже окна проводника (но не совсем правильно работает сворачивание приложений из магазина *Windows Store* — они остаются на панели задач).

Для того, чтобы вновь развернуть программу — просто нажимаем по её значку в области уведомлений.

Чтобы закрыть *RBTray* нажмите правой кнопкой мыши по значку любой программы, свёрнутой в трей и выберите пункт *«Exit RBTray»*. Чтобы не запускать каждый раз *RBTray*, вы можете добавить программу в автозагрузку *Windows 10*.

Официальная страница, на которой можно скачать [RBTray](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rbtray/), программа не требует установки на компьютер: достаточно распаковать архив и запустить исполняемый файл, чтобы она заработала.

Answer (score 0):

Prepros когда работает всегда отображает значок в *области уведомлений*.

Чтобы развернуть окно надо нажать на значок в *области уведомлений*.
Следовательно, чтобы свернуть надо опять нажать на значок в *области уведомлений*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]